# One application, multiple instances, different memory usage

Tags: node.js, v8, heap-memory

I have node.js server running two instances in cluster mode (via pm2).

The two instances are obviously identical, they execute the same code, load the same data.

Yet memory usage differs by over 100%:

Instance 1: 303,592kB
Instance 2: 614,404kB

Is there any reason the OS (Linux) can cause this behavior? The machine has plenty or RAM, so I would exclude memory shortage.

Answer (score 0):

Have the two servers been running for the same amount of time? Did they answer the same requests?

Node.js is a garbage-collected runtime. Memory use over time is not constant. The garbage collector kicks in depending on allocation behavior, heap size and limit, idleness, and possibly other factors. Maybe your instance 1 has just done a major round of garbage collection, and instance 2 is about to do one? Have you watched their memory usage over time?

Comment: Both instances are started at the same time (max a few seconds difference). They are loadbalanced (via pm2, round robin), but memory usage differs right from startup. And this happens sometimes, in other times the memory usage is identical.
Good point with the GC, was also my first thought. So I was reading everything I found about the v8 GC for the last week. And I can see the GC working in the statistics for other servers, under certain conditions they produce a nice sawtooth graph. However, in this case the memory usage does not vary a lot.